# Advanced Custom Fields Sub_Field in Archive Page

Tags: wordpress, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF plugin with repeater addon in Wordpress, Normally in archive.php I can use `get_field` or `the_field` functions and these are showing posts' data. (ex: title)

In single.php there is no problem, When i want to use `the_sub_field` or `get_sub_field` in `archive.php`,

[Image of Repeater Field Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n2dP.png)

In `archive.php`, the example below shows me No word. How can I see the Yes word? What should I do? Thank you.

```
<?php
    if( have_rows('add_content') ):
        echo "Yes";
    else :
        echo "No";
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Not have a repeater... (if it doesn't have add_content it will say no).

Comment: The post has add_content data, but in archive pages, i couldn't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an if/while statement for a repeater to work.

```
 <?php if (have_rows('add_content')){ ?>
     <?php while (have_rows('add_content')) { the_row(); ?>
        Yes
     <?php } // while:   ?>
 <?php } else { ?>
       No
 <?php }  ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Aibrean, but it is working in single.php, it is not working in archive.php, i mean in categories page, it doesn't get the repeater data from  any post.

For example, i have a post and it has repeater fields. In category page, i can't get the data of repeater fields of that post.

Comment: Are you putting it in the loop for that post?